# Flask-Superadmin - 'module' object has no attribute 'FileField'

Tags: python, flask

I'm tring to launch simple code from the docs:

https://flask-superadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.superadmin import Admin

app = Flask(__name__)

admin = Admin(app)

app.run()
```

but the following error occures:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask.ext.superadmin import Admin
  File "/home/un1t/workspace/dj/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 62, in load_module
    __import__(realname)
  File "/home/un1t/workspace/dj/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_superadmin/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from model import ModelAdmin
  File "/home/un1t/workspace/dj/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_superadmin/model/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import ModelAdmin, AdminModelConverter
  File "/home/un1t/workspace/dj/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_superadmin/model/base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from flask_superadmin.form import BaseForm, ChosenSelectWidget, DatePickerWidget, \
  File "/home/un1t/workspace/dj/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_superadmin/form.py", line 115, in <module>
    class FileField(wtf.FileField):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FileField'
```

I use the following versions of libraries:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Script==0.6.2
Flask-SuperAdmin==1.7
Flask-WTF==0.9.1
flask-mongoengine==0.7.0
WTForms==1.0.4
```

What is wrong, or where could I find working examples?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the import. I fixed it in my [fork](https://github.com/burhan/Flask-SuperAdmin); clone from there and then try it again.